# js doesnt execute extern function to recieve data from db

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, object

I'm trying to receive same version data from my MySQL (MariaDB) Server.
For better maintenance i created one connection Object to handle all database queries.
However when I query some data, it seems like it isn't executed in time, but later when the first await command appears.

dbControl.js :

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); 

function getConnection(){      

    let dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: ""
      });
              
    dbConnection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    this.get_version = function() {
        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM versionControl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;' 
        dbConnection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("vData:", result);
            return result;

        });
        
    }

}

module.exports.getConnection = getConnection;
```

dataHandler.js:

```
const browserControl = require('./browserControl');
const dbControl = require('../db/dbControl');

const dbConnection = new dbControl.getConnection();

let versionData;
// Here it should be executed -->
versionData = dbConnection.get_version();

console.log(versionData);


async function get_something(){

    // Here it is executed -->
    const browser = await browserControl.startBrowser();

    //......
}
```

There is a 3th file which simply controls the program. At the moment it just executes the function get_something() like:

```
const originData = require('./dataHandler.js');


let data = originData.get_something();
console.log(data);
```

P.s.: its all running with node, thanks in advance ;_)

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_something()` is marked as async.
Call it with `await get_something()` or `get_something().then(console.log)`.

Comment: If I do this I get:

"SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: Ok. Wrap this with: ` ;(async () => {... call here})()`

Comment: still isn't executed immediately, still console.log(versionData); gives me "undefined". And to be honest I don't get how the async should help a this place, cause in my opinion I don't like to wait for the hole process to be executed, but I wanna wait at a certain point in the process to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got a solution. The SQL query function returns a promise now and I created an extra "getVersion"-async-function which is waiting for the resolve of the promise. Thus the promise waits for the db answer and the rest waits until the promise is resolved.

the dataHandler.js now looks like this:

```
const browserControl = require('./browserControl');
const dbControl = require('../db/dbControl');

const dbConnection = new dbControl.getConnection();

async function getVersion() {
    let versionData;
    versionData = await dbConnection.get_version();
    console.log(versionData);
}

getVersion();


async function get_something(){
        
    const browser = await browserControl.startBrowser();

}
```

and the query-function now looks like this:

```
 this.get_version = function() {

        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM versionControl.lol_scraper ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;' 

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            dbConnection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("vData:", result);
                resolve(result);
            })
            
        });
```

P.s.: still open for smarter or more modern solutions ;_)